# The revenge of 3D light bulbs

Tags: visual, grid-deduction, three-dimensional

> This is a three-dimensional **Akari** puzzle (also known as **Light Up**). The five squares represent the layers of a $5\times5\times5$ cube, top to bottom. The objective is to add light bulbs into any number of cells so that the resulting grid satifies the following rules:<sup>1</sup>
>
> - Black cells are walls and cannot contain light bulbs.
> - Numbers in black cells indicate how many light bulbs are directly adjacent to that cell (vertically, horizontally or along the Z-axis).
> - A light bulb illuminates its own cell as well as every cell visible from it in all six directions (up/down, right/left, and both ways along the Z-axis), continuing until a wall comes in the way.
> - Every white square must be illuminated by at least one light bulb.
> - No light bulb may be illuminated by another light bulb.
>
> **Note**: The solution is unique and solvable by logic alone. No guesswork or trial-and-error is necessary here.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup> Paraphrased from the original rules on [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/akari.html)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took some notes on the picture:

> [image]

Comment: This is correct. Nice work!

Comment: #3 column 2 row 3 - what bulb lights that cell?

Comment: There's an unblocked bulb in the top layer, on c2, r3.